# delivering ebook throught mobile app

Tags: interfaces, mobile, ebook

I have designed the interface of a mag app which would deliver digitized magazine in the size of A3 paper to the mobile phone.

My choice of fileformat is jpg of each of the pages, but is there any better way to do this that using jpeg format.

The file for one sample magazine was 16MB, and I'm stuck weather to deliver page by page or as a whole file which can be flipped

Comment: your customers will just love you for sending 16MB images to their cellphones and expecting them to be able to read the text on them with their tiny screens...

Comment: whats your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ePub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) is a standard format for e-books.  In particular, the ePub v3 standard is designed for texts that require specific layouts, like magazines and comic books.  Being a standard, many e-book readers can already display ePub files.  So you might not even need an app (if you don't want one).  Another option is, of course, PDF, which can be viewed on most devices as well.

Delivering the magazine as a JPG per page would take a lot of bandwidth and storage space.  And since you aren't delivering text, would make it difficult for readers to search.

Comment: The magazine is designed and printed in coreldarw, and i would like to keep its layout. Is this possible in epub

Comment: ePub is basically HTML, so if you can do it in HTML you can probably do it in ePub.  Whether Corel supports that or not, I have no idea.

Comment: I was just looking around, and it looks like more recent versions of InDesign and Quark Xpress can output ePub.